# How to statically build dart sdk?

Tags: dart, libc

I simply found dart can't get running in Ubuntu 7.

It requires a higher version of libc.

When compile nodejs, they have an static building option, so the final node binary executable can get running without libc or shared_library.

How can I do the same thing with dart?

[image]